# Как запустить внутри своего приложения vlcj плеер?

Tags: java, javafx, vlc

Делаю проект на JavaFX, нужно чтоб в окошке располагались 2 таблички и под ними плеер.

Скажите пожалуйста как добавить к себе на форму vlcj плеер, у меня что то ничего не получается. В главный `FXML` я добавил `SplitPane` и пытаюсь в него загрузить плеер, вот так:

```
playerController = new VLCPlayerController();
playerController.initialize(null, null);
splitPane.getItems().add(0, playerController);
```

Код самого плеера взял [отсюда](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj-javafx) и с небольшими доработками добавил к себе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо самому создавать какой-либо контроллер. Это делает за Вас сам javafx.

Если **fxml** имеет следующий вид :

```
<SplitPane fx:id="myId" fx:controller="VLCPlayerController">
 ...
</SplitPane>
```

То загружать этот контроллер надо в модели, и делается это следующим образом

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(resources) // resources - путь до fxml файла
    SplitPane splitPane = loader.load();
    VLCPlayerController playerController = loader.getController(); // на этом этапе у нас контроллер создается

//и тут уже добавлять сам плеер в splitPane ( или куда надо)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, плеер отображается и работает. ))